# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdowns Unclickable On Tablets

Tags: javascript, android, twitter-bootstrap, tablet

On the menus for our site we have a button dropdown for user account options that changes dynamically based on their username and logged in status. It works great in the browsers, however, on Android tablets(using Firefox) we can't seem to click any of the links in the dropdown, although the links DO appear, whenever you click them the dropdown goes away and nothing happens.

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap(2.1.1), with the [dropdown plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns). It works on desktops, and it's clickable by the tablets, the links just close the popup when clicked.

Here's the code:

```
     <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="icon-user"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/Profile">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#" onClick="logOut();">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Does anyone know of a way to make the links clickable from tablets?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem, do you found a solution?

Comment: I haven't yet, I just started making separate links from the dropdown links in other locations on the website, so it's a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in Bootstrap that will hopefully be rectified in 2.1.2 - in the meantime, there are two popular issues ([#2975](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2975) & [#4550](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550)) on GitHub that contain temporary fixes.

This jQuery fix seems to work for most people and doesn't modify the Bootstrap source:

```
$('body').on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Just curious, do you think that something like this would work on a lightbox that's unclickable (but shouldn't be) on mobile too?

Comment: Something similar might work (this fix is specific to dropdowns on Bootstrap), but it's hard to say without seeing some code. What plugin are you using?

Comment: We rolled our own - anyway, I won't hijack this thread, I'll post my own question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: upgrade to >= v2.2...this is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

To fix submenus too:

```
$('body').on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
         .on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-submenu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is confrmed fixed in v2.2 and greater.